# IF statement in power BI

Tags: dax

I was hoping someone could help with this DAX please:

I am trying to say if the required date is greater than the completion date and the days remaining is not null,then True else False.
I get an unexpected tuple error. They are two date columns and a whole number column for days remaining
Could anyone help please?

IF(AND(Column1[required date] > Column1[Completion date] NOT(ISBLANK(Column1[Days Remaining] , TRUE, False)

Thank you anyone for any help.

Comment: You forgot a comma in AND, also didn't close  AND with ")"` IF( AND ( Column1[required date] > Column1[Completion date] , NOT(ISBLANK(Column1[Days Remaining]) , TRUE, False)`

Comment: @Mik thank you for your reply. Sadly I still get red squiggly lines and unexpected tuple error

Comment: Are you dealing with the calculated column ?

Comment: @Mik yes its a calculated column

Comment: once again check the spelling,. I didn't see that NOT is not closed as well )  or try this expression `IF( AND ( Column1[required date] > Column1[Completion date] , NOT(ISBLANK(Column1[Days Remaining]) ), TRUE, False)`

Comment: Is it a complete expression or you have something else in the measure?

Comment: @Mik
I get red squiggly lines under the true false part with the error Unexpected parameter

Comment: @Mik
Is it a complete expression or you have something else in the measure?

Sorry, I dont know what that means

Comment: One more ")" is forgotten ). Check the answer

Comment: How does it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(
   AND(
      Column1[required date] > Column1[Completion date]
      ,NOT(ISBLANK(Column1[Days Remaining]))
   )
    ,TRUE
    ,False
)
```